# Checking if today's date is in between the given start date and end date

Tags: postgresql

The code is written in postgresql and run in pgadmin 4.

I am trying to get the id from the pricing table if the current date lies in between the given start date and end date.

I am trying to get the id from the pricing table if the current  date lies in between the given start date and end date.

```
select id

from pricing 

where current_Date between start_date>=date '2022-10-19' AND end_date<=date '2022-10-20';
```

The error raises

> operator does not exist: date >= boolean LINE 3:     where
> current_Date between start_date>=date '2022-10-19'...

Comment: The docs are there for a reason [Comparison Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html): *The BETWEEN predicate simplifies range tests: a BETWEEN x AND y is equivalent to a >= x AND a <= y*

Answer (score 0):

`between` only expects the values:

```
select id

from pricing 

where current_Date between '2022-10-19' AND '2022-10-20';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` condition is essentially `someDate between someBoolean and someOtherBoolean`, which confuses compiler. Use just this:

```
where current_Date between date '2022-10-19' AND date '2022-10-20'
```